# Ruby: sort an array exluding some symbols

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have such an array: `["c", "-b", "a"]`

`["c", "-b", "a"].sort!` returns `["-b", "a", "c"]`

I want it to be sorted like `["a", "-b", "c"]`

How do I exclude the minus sign from sorting?
What's the simplest way to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
["c", "-b", "a"].sort_by{|e| e[/\w+/] }
# => ["a", "-b", "c"]
```

Comment: Good, Arup.  To generalize to disregard a minus sign at the beginning of any string (but leave embedded ones): `sort_by {|e| e.match(/(?:^-)?(.+)/)[1]}`.  I was trying to express this as `e[/??/]`, but could figure out how.  Can you (or anyone else) help?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `'-a-b'[/^-?(.+)$/,1] # => "a-b"`

Comment: Better yet: `'-a-b'[/\w.*/] # => "a-b"`

Comment: @Matt Very Very Veryyyyyy Good!!

Comment: Thx*2, @Matt.  Re "better yet", to apply to all strings (including those with a non-`\w` after a beginning minus): `'-:a-b'[/[^-].*/]`.

Answer (score 2):

This ignores all non-alphanumeric symbols, and works for strings of any length:

```
["c", "-b", "a"].sort_by { |s| s.gsub(/\W/,'') }
# => ["a", "-b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works, but `sort_by` is more direct:

```
["c", "-b", "a"].sort {|x,y| x[/\w+/] <=> y[/\w+/]} # => ["a", "-b", "c"]
```

Edit: Better, I think:

```
["c", "-b", "a"].sort {|x,y| x[/[^-]+/] <=> y[/[^-]+/]}
```